# How to use admob without implementation App Id in manifest

Tags: admob

I want to use Google Admob with this version of google play service.
"  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0' ".

But it's not run without initializing appId in the manifest file.
Is there any other way to use this implementation without initializing appId in the manifest file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Google Ad Manager instead of AdMob

```
<manifest>
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
        android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/announcing-v1700-of-android-google.html